# Get index and name of checked item in checkedListbox

Tags: c#

I am new to winForms. I am trying to make an app where there is a checkedlist of items, and when the user checks an item there is a message that shows the index and the name of the checked item.

Here is what I have written so far, but the problem is that when I select the first item nothing happens, when I select another I see the previous one etc.

```html
 void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
         foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {

            
            MessageBox.Show("Item with title: \"" + itemChecked.ToString() +
                            "\", is checked. Checked state is: " +
                            checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(itemChecked)).ToString() + ".");
         }
```

Comment: So the log appears delayed by one click? I guess the function is called when an item is clicked. That means the "CheckedItems" list is not updated yet. You could just look into the ItemCheckEventArgs and find out which item was clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out the [Remarks on `CheckedListBox.ItemChecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck#remarks) it states

> The check state is not updated until after the ItemCheck event occurs.

When you check the first item in your `CheckedListBox`, your event triggers but the check state of the item has not updated yet. So, there are no items in `checkedListBox1.CheckedItems` and so there isn't a message box displayed.

When you check a second item, the only item in `checkedListBox1.CheckedItems` is the one you previously checked. So, that is the one that displays.

I'm assuming from the question that you just want to show the item whose check state is being modified. If so, you can use the [`ItemCheckEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.itemcheckeventargs) to get the information you need.

```
void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Item with title \"" + checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString() + 
"\" was checked. The new check state is " + e.NewValue.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can get the index of the selected in the `ItemCheckEventArgs e`, just like this:

```
int Index =  e.Index ;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to know when an item has been CHECKED, thus use code like this:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        String item = checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Index " + e.Index + " checked: " + item);
    }
}
```

This will work regardless of how the item was checked; thru `SetItemChecked()`, using the space bar while an item is selected, or clicking on the checkbox portion with the mouse.